# Wrong when creating new folder in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My hadoop-1.2.1 configurations are blow:

```
***core-site.xml***

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/dsk/hadoop/tmp-storage</value>
    </property>
</configuration>


***hdfs-site.xml***


<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I want to use Hadoop Filesystem API to make new direction in HDFS. So I wrote in my code:

```
    @Test
    public void testDirectory() throws Exception {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        FileSystem hdfs = HDFSUtils.getFileSystem(configuration);
        Path path = new Path("/test_dir");
        boolean isSuccess = hdfs.mkdirs(path);
        System.out.println("mkdir   test_dir" + (isSuccess ? " success" : " failure"));
    }
```

My `class HDFSUtils` is :

```
    public static FileSystem getFileSystem(Configuration conf) {

        FileSystem hdfs = null;
        try {

            hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            return hdfs;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hdfs;
    }
```

I want my hdfs  hierarchical structure like below:
[image]
But I got `mkdir test_dir failure` when I tested with JUnit.

My working IDE is Eclipse, in `conf` folder two `xml` files having been included[image]

I still have some problems on how to manipulate files on HDFS using Filesystem API. 
At first I used `URL` method and it worked.

```
String fileUrl = "hdfs://localhost:9000/firstSQL.sql";
```

But when I changed it to HDFS FileSystem API, I can't find my files:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem hdfs = HDFSUtils.getFileSystem(conf);
    Path path = new Path("/firstSQL.sql");
```

The Failure Traces is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /firstSQL.sql does not exist.`

But I really have `firstSQL.sql` in HDFS.
[image]

I am confused of the **real path of my file** on HDFS.

Comment: Can you try `Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);` and let us know ??

Comment: I have added the implementation of `class HDFSUtils` and its public method `getFileSystem(Configuration)`.:-)

Comment: I packed your method in `class HDFSUtils`, what they do are actually the same. @Mr.Chowdary

Comment: Please try to do [this](http://blog.rajeevsharma.in/2009/06/using-hdfs-in-java-0200.html) where checking whether path exists or not and all other operations exist. check what operations working and what not..

Comment: The article you provided helped a lot, instead of using only`Configure conf = new Configuration()`, should we added `conf.addResource(new Path("xxxxxx"));` Thanks for that.